# Python & Pandas - convert table with header rows to item level rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with header level rows

```
header_col1    header_col2    item_col1
A              111            apple | banana
B              222            apple
C              333            pear | grapes
D              444            grapes
```

I would like to transform this dataset so that each row in the table represents an item instead a header.
That is:

```
header_col1    header_col2    item_col1
A              111            apple
A              111            banana
B              222            apple
C              333            pear
C              333            grapes
D              444            grapes
```

Is there any simple way to do this with pandas?
All I can think of are

Comment: It looks like this might be the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`.str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) to split the strings into lists and then use [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to expand the lists into separate rows (one row per string).  Finally, strip out extra white spaces around the strings during split with [`.str.strip()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), as follows:

```
df['item_col1'] = df['item_col1'].str.split('|')
df = df.explode('item_col1').reset_index()
df['item_col1'] = df['item_col1'].str.strip()


print(df)

   index header_col1  header_col2 item_col1
0      0           A          111     apple
1      0           A          111    banana
2      1           B          222     apple
3      2           C          333      pear
4      2           C          333    grapes
5      3           D          444    grapes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"header_col1":['A','A','B','C','C','D'],
                     'header_col2':[111,111,222,333,333,444],
                      'item_col1':['apple','banana','apple','pear','grapes','grapes']})
data.explode('header_col1')
```

Link to explode documentation [click here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)